# Ctrl keys don't work, need to debug hardware or software

Tags: keyboard

Neither of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys work. I have a Lenovo Yoga 13 with OpenSUSE 15, and have set the BIOS to switch the left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Fn</kbd>. In that case the left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (now mapped to <kbd>Fn</kbd>) works.

I get nothing on `showkey -k` on `tty1`.

How do I make sure if it's a hardware issue or software?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `xev` command and check keysyms/keycodes output.

Little white box will popup, press `Ctrl` and check the output.

Comment: `xev` doesn't give anything either. And I think (?) `showkey` is at the kernel level, so should be a better check for hw problems.

Comment: How about trying some other distro Live CD, and check if `Ctrl` is working that way? If it doesn't, it might be hardware issue.